# stata - variable operations conditional to existent vars and to a list of varnames

Tags: stata

I have this problem.
My dataset has variables like:

sec20_var1 sec22_var1 sec30_var1 
sec20_var2 sec22_var2 sec30_var2 sec31_var2

(~102 sectors, ~60 variables, not all of the cominations are complete or even existent)

My intention is to build an indicator that do an average of variables within sector. So it is an "aggregated sector" that contains sectors belonging to a class in a high-med-low technology fashion. I already have the definitions of what sectors should include in each category. Let's say, in high technology I should put sec20 and sec31.

The problem: the list of sectors belonging to a class and the actual sectors available for each variable doesn't match. So I'm stucked with this problem and started to do it manually. My best approach was:

```
set more off
foreach v in _var02  {
    ds *`v'
    di "`r(varlist)'"
    local sects`v' `r(varlist)'
        foreach s in sec26 sec28 sec37  {
        capture confirm local sects`v'
        if !_rc {
            egen oecd_medhigh_avg_`v'=rowmean(`s'`v' sec28`v' sec37`v' sec40`v' sec59`v' sec92`v' sec54`v' sec55`v' sec48`v' sec50`v' sec53`v' sec4`v' sec5`v' sec6`v')               
    else {
        di "`v' didnt existed"
            }
}
}
}
```

I got it work only with those variables that has all the sectors present in the totalrow (which is simpler since I dont have to store the varlist in a macro). I would like to do an average of the AVAILABLE sectors, even if they are only two per variable.

I also noticed that the macro storage could be helpful but I don't know how to put it into my code. I'm totally stucked in here.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Rho--have you been able to figure this out? Was my answer helpful or are you still stuck?

Comment: @SOConnell> Thanks a lot! I've posted my work around too. I still dont know if the "elegant" solution without creating missings is possible. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @SOConnell. As I said in my comment, I went to the same direction, but I'm still searching for the solution I expected (that I don't how to program it or even if it's possible).

I used this code, that goes in the same direction that the one made by @SOConnell, but I found this one more clear. The trick is the `_rc==111` that catches the missing combinations of **sector_X_variable** and complete them, with the objective of beeing used in the second part. Everything worked. It's not elegant, but it has some practical use. :) The third part erases the missing variables created.

*COMPLETING THE LIST OF COMBINATIONS
    set more off
    foreach v in _var02 _var03 _var08 _var13 _... {
    foreach s in sec27 sec35 sec42 sec43 sec45 sec46 sec39 sec52 sec67 {
    capture confirm variable `s'`v'
    if _rc==111 {
         gen `s'`v'=.
    }
    }
    }
*GENERATING THE INDICATOR WITH ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS
    set more off
    foreach v in _var02 _var03 _var08 _var13 ... {
    egen oecd_high_avg_`v'=rowmean(sec27`v' sec35`v' sec42`v' sec43`v' sec45`v' sec46`v' sec39`v' sec52`v' sec67`v')
    }
*DROPPING MISSING VARIABLES CREATED TO DO THE INDICATOR.
set more off
foreach v of varlist *  {
gen TEMP=.
replace TEMP=1 if !missing(`v')
egen TEMPSUM=sum(TEMP)
if TEMPSUM==0 {
di "                             >>>  Dropping empty variable:`v'"
drop `v'
}
drop TEMP TEMPSUM
}

Note that I cutted the list of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I will call what you are referring to as variables as "accounts".

The workaround would be to create empty variables in the dataset for all sectorXaccount combinations. From a point where you already have your dataset loaded into memory:

```
forval sec = 1/102 {
    forval account = 1/60 {
    cap gen sec`sec'_var`account'=. /*this will skip over generating the secXaccount combination if it already exists in the dataset */
    }
}
```

Then apply the rowmean operation to the full definition of each indicator. The missings won't be calculated into your rowmean, so it will effectively be an average of available cells without you having to do the selection manually. You could then probably automate deleting the empty variables you created if you do something like:

```
g start=.
forval sec = 1/102 {
    forval account = 1/60 {
    cap gen sec`sec'_var`account'=.  /*this will skip over generating the secXaccount combination if it already exists in the dataset */
    }
}
g end=.

[indicator calculations go here]

drop start-end
```

However, it seems like you would be creating averages that might not be comparable (some will have 2 underlying values, some 3, some 4, etc.) so you need to be careful there (but you are probably already aware of that).

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but I see no advantage in creating variables just to contain missings, which will then be ignored. What's wrong with just seeking the right wildcard?

Comment: Yes; my response is more a workaround. It's definitely not pretty. I sort of figured the OP already thought through doing this with wildcards. Maybe that's the simpler and more elegant way on this one.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot. I've actually solved it, also with a similar workaround, which is, to complete the dataset with missing variables (that will be ommitted in the rowmean). I wasn't "happy" though because I wanted to do it with specific references to the actual variables (only existent ones ...cause I have stata-se and I'm very close to the 5000vars limit!). So, my idea was to store the list of available variables in a macro and then "do the match" with the list of "ideal categories" (which combinations does not necessarly existed in the dataset). I'm still don't know if that's possible. :)

Comment: By the way... that listing `1/60` x `1/102` although it is the "actually more complete dataset" was impossible to handle in my stata-se. I made a custom list that contemplates a selected group of variables. Nice trick with cap gen!!!
Thanks a lOt :)

Comment: I didn't realize the limitations with SE--cool to see your solution under those constraints. Cheers.